# Symfony2 - MopaBootstrapBundle - how to remove form styling, but still use Collection type

Tags: forms, symfony, twitter-bootstrap-3, collections

All I want is nice Collection type with add and remove buttons and I tried using `BraincraftedBootstrapBundle`, but I really hated, that it styled my forms and if I configured it not to style, then I wasn't able to use collection type functionality it provided. I decided to try `MopaBootstrapBundle` instead, but I am facing similar problem. My form is styled according to bundle and if I configure not to style:

```
mopa_bootstrap:
    form:
        templating: false
```

My form is unstyled again as I want it, but then collection type is not working. The things I do not like is that form are getting `form-horizontal`, inputs - `form-controls` and labels - `form-labels` classes. Any ideas what am I missing?

I would like bundle not to style my form fields except collection type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite the default style of mopaBootstrap.

In your conf do:

```
mopa_bootstrap:
    form:
        templating: YourBundle:Form:fields.html.twig
```

Then in your custom fields.html.twig use only the collection_widget block (https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig):

```
{% block collection_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
{% if prototype is defined %}
    {% set prototype_markup = form_row(prototype) %}
    {% set data_prototype_name = form.vars.form.vars.prototype.vars.name|default('__name__') %}
    {% set data_prototype_label = form.vars.form.vars.prototype.vars.label|default('__name__label__') %}
    {% set widget_form_group_attr = widget_form_group_attr|merge({
        'data-prototype': prototype_markup,
        'data-prototype-name': data_prototype_name,
        'data-prototype-label': data_prototype_label
    })|merge(attr) %}
{% endif %}
{# Add row by default use attr.class to change#}
{% if 'collection' in form.vars.block_prefixes and attr.class is defined %}
    {% set widget_form_group_attr = widget_form_group_attr|merge({'class': widget_form_group_attr.class|default('row') ~ ' ' ~ attr.class}) %}
{% endif %}
{# collection item adds class {form_id}_form-group  too #}
{% set widget_form_group_attr = widget_form_group_attr|merge({'id': 'collection' ~ id ~ '_form_group', 'class': widget_form_group_attr.class ~ ' collection-items ' ~ id ~ '_form_group'}) %}

<div {% for attrname,attrvalue in widget_form_group_attr %} {{attrname}}="{{attrvalue}}"{% endfor %}>
{# Add initial prototype form #}
{% if form.vars.value|length == 0 and prototype is defined %}
    {% for name in prototype_names %}
        {{ prototype_markup|replace({'__name__': name})|raw }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{{ block('form_widget') }}
</div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock collection_widget %}
```

Something like this should do the trick.